# Jquery mousemove on svg not working

Tags: jquery, html, svg, mousemove

I am trying to show a `Information Box` when hovering/moving over an svg image. I place the box based on the position of the mouse and retrieve data from the server. The box is `absolute` positioned.
The mousemove event does not fire at all when i move the pointer over the svg.
This is the code I am using (simplified).

```
    $('.trigger').mousemove(function(e) {
        //var parentOffset = $(this).parent().offset();
        // var relX = e.pageX - parentOffset.left;
        // var relY = e.pageY - parentOffset.top;

        $('.target').css('visibility', 'visible');
        $('.target').css('left', e.pageX);
        $('.target').css('top', e.pageY);
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
```

**P.S.** Occasionally the event fires once right after page load.

**EDIT:**
I used the following css rule for pointer events.

```
.target * {
    pointer-events: none !important;
}
```

Comment: Is your svg image inline or is it included via a tag e.g.`<object>`. You really need to show more code.

Comment: added via `<object>` tag

Comment: The contents of the object tag will swallow the mouse events unless you make them pointer-events:none

Comment: I had tried with `pointer-events:none` on the object tag. doesn't work.

Comment: I didn't say on the object tag, I said on the **contents** of the object tag.

Comment: I added a css rule (see edit) but it gets ignored. even setting the rule per element (from developer tools panel in chrome) doesn't work either.

Comment: You need to set it in the SVG file, you can't do this in the container except by getting a reference to the contents via javascript.